# Cannot dynamically compile code from a file as namespace 'MySql' cannot be found

Tags: c#, mysql, compilation

The objective of the application is to perform statistical analysis on data from a table. The exact makeup of the data/table is determined during run-time by user input, i.e. number and type of columns.
I'm able to dynamically create the table but am having trouble filling it with data. The code to fill the table is dynamically created and should only need to be run once. It's basically a bunch of loops generating numbers.
I can take the same code that is dynamically generated and create a class in an existing project with it - the code compiles and runs just fine. However, when trying to compile it dynamically I get the following error :
The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
I've tried adding 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.dll', as a CompilerParameter without success. Adding it to the main program as a NuGet Packet doesn't solve the problem either.
So how to I add 'MySql.Data' to the parameter list?

```
 CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();

            cp.GenerateExecutable = true;
            cp.OutputAssembly = exeName;
            cp.GenerateInMemory = false;
            cp.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("MySql.Data.MySqlClient.dll"); //doesn't work!

            CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, inSourceName);
```

Here is the dynamically generated code. It's been stripped down to the bare minimum for testing purposes. If I can get this to compile the rest should work just fine :

```
 string[] programText1 =
        {
            "using System;",
            "using System" + '\u002E' + "Data;",
            "using MySql" + '\u002E' + "Data" + '\u002E' + "MySqlClient;",
            "namespace Mouse",
            "{",
            "\tstatic class Program",
            "\t{",
            "\t\tstatic string masterConnString = \"Server = localhost; User Id = root; Persist Security Info = True; database = testing_database; Password = sql832SQL *#@;\";",
            "\t\tstatic MySqlConnection masterConnection = new MySqlConnection(masterConnString);",
            "",
            "\t\tstatic void Main()",
            "\t\t{",
            "\t\t\tConsole.WriteLine(\"Hello Cruel World!\");",
            "\t\t\tConsole.ReadLine();",
            "\t\t}"
        };
```

Comment: So... when you've changed path of "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.dll" to an absolute one that definitely has that file - did it start working? Please [edit] question with this info (and ideally clarify ` //doesn't work!` comment at the same time).

Comment: Alexei Levenkov thanks for the pointer. MySql.Data.MySqlClient is the namespace but the assembly is just MySql.Data. Therefor there is not .MySqlClient.dll file to be found. I was missing a few items. 1) in the parameters list the assemblies for System, System.Data and System.XML; 2) in the code to be compiled both the namespaces MySql.Data and MySql.Data.MySqlClient needed to be present. Do you want me to post the final code here for others?

Comment: You are welcome to post your finding as an answer (self-answering is perfectly fine especially in situation like this - you asked well received question and found answer later, most complains about self-answered posts are when one tries to ask question they already  have answer too resulting in poor question). Alternatively you can do nothing and eventually someone may convert your comment to complete answer (which is also welcome behavior on SO). The only thing you should not do is adding answer into the question (as it no longer be a question).